# VS Code: Generate boilerplate code when creating a new component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, boilerplate

I am wondering if there is a way to configure VS Code to generate Typescript/ React boilerplate code when creating a new component.
For example when I create a new component named `myComponent.tsx` I would like the file to be pre-filled with

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface props {}

export const MyComponent: React.FC<props> = (): JSX.Element => (
  <div>
    {"MyComponent"}
  </div>
);
```

I found [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Magssch.react-typescript-boilerplate) but the generated boilerplate doesn't match what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a custom snippet:

- Press F1
- Preferences: Configure User Snippets
- typescriptreact.json

```
{
  "boilerplate": {
    "prefix": "boilerplate",
    "body": [
      "import * as React from \"react\";",
      "",
      "export interface props {}",
      "",
      "export const $TM_FILENAME_BASE: React.FC<props> = (): JSX.Element => (",
      "\t<div>",
      "\t\t{\"$TM_FILENAME_BASE\"}",
      "\t</div>",
      ");"
    ]
  }
}
```

Then, in a `.tsx` file, typing `boilerplate` would suggest the code above which would write exactly the code you want.

Comment: That is what I was looking for, thanks!